# Setting up a channel for communicating between Dart and js in an embedded WebView

Tags: webview, flutter, openlayers

Need to build an application having the Map feature built on top of the OpenLayers lib. This app was built by the native languages on both platforms (ios and android) and it works fine. Now, we want to migrate to the flutter to gain the benefits of the "code once" terminology. Flutter seems to be the best choice except the webview plugin developed by the Flutter team. It is not supporting the communication between dart and js :-(. Also going through some plugins in the community but no luck to find the suitable one. Someone have a good idea and please advise. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

i know it's too late but it may help to other.

Here is an example of communication from Javascript code to flutter.

In Flutter build your WebView like :

```
WebView(
          initialUrl: url,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          javascriptChannels: Set.from([
            JavascriptChannel(
                name: 'Print',
                onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                  //This is where you receive message from 
                  //javascript code and handle in Flutter/Dart
                  //like here, the message is just being printed
                  //in Run/LogCat window of android studio
                  print(message.message);
                })
          ]),
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController w) {
            webViewController = w;
          },
        )
```

and in Your HTMLfile:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
Print.postMessage('Hello World being called from Javascript code');
</script>
```

When you run this code, you shall be able to see log "Hello World being called from Javascript code" in the LogCat/Run window of android studio

if u want to send msg from dart to js then here is your example:-

```
 flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript('var x = document.getElementsByClassName("layout__area--top"); x[0].style.opacity =0;');
```